# jQuery - onClick of an anchor tag move to dynamically created div li element and highlight it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a table with values fetched from ajax call and each  has an anchor tag with data-id attribute.

Also I have created a timeline view(hidden by default) dynamically with the same values and has a scrollview - as there are 1000 events.

When a user clicks on the anchor tag in  how can I move to that particular li element in timeline and hide the table.

```js
function create_table(data) {
  var tr = $('<tr>');
  $.each(data, function(idx, ele) {
      tr.append("<<td><p><a class='details' data-id='" + data['id'] + "href=" + data['link'] + "> Link </a></p></td>")
    }
    $('tbody').append(tr);
  }

  function create_time(data) {
    var ul = $("<ul>");
    $.each(data, function(idx, ele) {
        ul.append("<li id=" + data['id'] + "><div>" +
          data['player_name'] + "</div></li>");
      }
      $(".vertical-timeline").append(ul)
    }

    $("a.details").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".player_div").hide();
      $(".player_timeline").show();

      // MOVE TO PARTICULAR LI 

    });

    CSS
      .player_timeline {
        height: 700 px;
        margin - bottom: 100 px;
      }

      .vertical - timeline {
        overflow - y: scroll;
        height: 500 px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="player-div">
  <table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</section <section class="player_timeline" style="display:none;">
<div class="vertical-timeline">
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Without your code it can be very hard to provide you with a correct answer, since we can only guess what your code looks like

Comment: sorry adding the code

Comment: @RinsenS have you tried `$(document).on("click","a.details",function(e){`?

Comment: actually this works $("a.details").on("click", function(e){  } , I am able to get the id from <a> tag, but I am not able to scroll to li as the entire timeline is in its own scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery, you can attach a event like this

```
$("a.details").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".player_div").hide();
    $(".player_timeline").show();

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".player_timeline").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    $(".player_timeline").animate({
      scrollTop: $('li to scroll').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: No it didn't work. As the entire timeline is in its own scrollview - i am not able to reach to that element.

Comment: Then you need to perform two scrolls, first to the parent of second scroll view and then another scroll inside the view. But I was just giving you an idea

Comment: Yes I need to do that but I am not able to find a solution, and thanks for your idea too !!

Comment: its worked but i change few things, instead of offset i took position

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.details").on("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".player_div").hide();
$(".player_timeline").show();
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("li #" + id).offset().top - 1000 }, 'slow');
});
```

hope above code help you.